# How do I write a program that can send and receive Canbus/Canopen messages?

Tags: python, can-bus, canopen

I am completely new to the embedded systems part of electronics as I am mostly working with automation. But for my thesis a part of this is to make it possible to send and receive Canbus/Canopen messages with a program written in python. Where do I start and how do I go forward with this?

Comment: Also we will be doing this on a computer. We do have a pci-e to can converter

Comment: This question is too broad. Normally you'd buy some USB-to-CAN adapter and use the API/drivers provided by the manufacturer. But you would also need to know the specific higher layer protocol used, which is a big topic of its own.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.